# How to correctly set Expires headers on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The [Google Cloud Storage Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/developer-guide) explains how to set Cache-Control headers, and explains their critical impact on the consistency behavior of the api, yet the Expires headers aren't mentioned nor did they appear to be inheriting from the Cache-Control configuration.

The Expires header appeared to always be equal to request time plus 1 year, regardless of Cache-Control setting, eg.

```
$ gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control:300" gs://example-bucket/doc.html
```

A request was made to a document (doc.html) in the Google Cloud Storage bucket (example-bucket) via

```
$ curl -I http://example-bucket.storage.googleapis.com/doc.html
```

which produced the following headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Oct 3 2012 16:52:30 (1349308350)
Date: Sat, 13 Oct 2012 00:51:13 GMT
Cache-Control: 300, no-transform
Expires: Sun, 13 Oct 2013 00:51:13 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Oct 2012 20:08:41 GMT
ETag: "28fafe4213ae34c7d3ebf9ac5a6aade8"
x-goog-sequence-number: 82
x-goog-generation: 1347601001449082
x-goog-metageneration: 1
Content-Type: text/html
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 7069
Vary: Origin
```

Comment: Looks like there may have been a bug recently (files downloaded in April 2018) that also caused a year-forward Expires header: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708712/google-cloud-storage-file-cache-and-expiry-issue#comment87050208_49708712, direct issue tracker report after logging in at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77842189

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you say the Expires header shows request time plus 1 year. In your example, the Expires header shows a timestamp one hour after the request date, which is to be expected.

I just did an experiment where I set an object's max age to 3600 and then 7200 via this command:

```
gsutil setmeta "Cache-Control:max-age=7200" gs://marc-us/xyz.txt
```

Then I retrieved the object using the gsutil cat command with the -D option to see the request/response details, like this:

```
gsutil -D cat gs://marc-us/xyz.txt
```

In both experiments, the Expires header produced the expected timestamp, as per the object's max-age setting (i.e. one hour after request time and two hours after request time).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I'll try this out with the gsutil tool. I've been using [fog](http://fog.io/1.6.0/index.html)

Comment: It definitely works correctly using the v2.0 api. I was [using the v1.0 api](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/google/requests/storage/put_object.rb). Perhaps the error is being introduced with the interaction library...

Comment: How is "Expires: Sun, 13 Oct 2013" not a year later than "Date: Sat, 13 Oct 2012"?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was caused by a malformed header. Duh.

```
Cache-Control: 300, no-transform
```

should be

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300, no-transform
```

When things are set correctly, they work. See [RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1) Section 14.9 (Cache-Control)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9).